# Qt Adding Layout within the main Layout

Tags: c++, qt, layout, widget

I am currently using Qt 5.5 with Mac OSX. I am trying to build a GUI system with a main layout with a console screen that shows some I/O and then also a gridlayout within the mainlayout that shows a series of buttons and drop down menus.

So the main layout would have a:

- mainlayout with a console and a nested gridlayout
- The gridlayout will have a variety of different widgets laid out the way I want.

Here is my code currently:

```
    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)

{
    //******* Set up
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // 01: Creation of Console
    console = new Console;
    console->setEnabled(false);

    //Drop Down Menu
    QGridLayout* gridbox = new QGridLayout();
    QStringList commands;
    commands << "Q" << "W" << "E" << "R";
    QComboBox* combo = new QComboBox();
    combo->addItems(commands);

    /************** Adding Widgets *********************/
    //02: Formatting Widgets
    //creation and attribution of slider
    slider = new QSlider();
    slider->resize(255, 20);
    slider->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
    slider->setRange(0, 255); //0-255 is range we can read

    //creation and attribution of the lcd
    lcd = new QLCDNumber();
    lcd->setSegmentStyle(QLCDNumber::Flat);
    lcd->resize(255, 50);

    //03: Adding widgets to layout
    QVBoxLayout* mainlayout = new QVBoxLayout(); //main layout for ui

    //add widgets to the grid 
    gridbox->addWidget(combo);
    gridbox->addWidget(slider);
    gridbox->addWidget(lcd);

    //add the grid to the mainlayout
    mainlayout->addLayout(gridbox);       

    ui->centralWidget->setLayout(mainlayout);           //create main layout
    ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(console);    //add the console to it
}
```

The problem I am having is in adding the gridlayout items and then the console. The gridlayout items are simply not showing up and I was wondering what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `mainlayout->show()` did you forget? or `centralWidget->show()`

Comment: But he does not say that main window is not showing. All the nested stuff supposed to show then.

Comment: mainWindow->show() is in my main.cpp file, it is the gridlayout that I am having a problem with

Answer (score 1):

The most usable method to put items in the grid of grid layout:

[void QGridLayout::addWidget(QWidget * widget, int fromRow, int fromColumn, int rowSpan, int columnSpan, Qt::Alignment alignment = 0)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-2)

Make sure to provide row, column, how many rows and how many columns the item supposed to take.

```
//add widgets to the grid 
gridbox->addWidget(combo,  0, 0, 1, 1);
gridbox->addWidget(slider, 0, 1, 1, 1));
gridbox->addWidget(lcd,    1, 0, 1, 2);
```

And resizing the widget before putting to layout may not work. You should rather provide either or both min or max size and/or size hint and/or sizing policy for the item.

Comment: I have done that, but the only widgets showing up are the ones added via  ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(...);

Comment: Try not to do that and only add the grid layout. What you see then? I suspect items not providing min size or not properly initialized. I would first play QLabel text items and see.